# Is Centos 7 affected by changes (June 2023) to RHEL source access?

Tags: redhat, centos7

In the last week Red Hat [announced changes to source code access](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/furthering-evolution-centos-stream) which is through to make is difficult (impossible?) for downstream rebuilds of RHEL to exist.  Red Hat [later clarified](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/red-hats-commitment-open-source-response-gitcentosorg-changes) that that was their intention in making this change.

My concern is that "back in the day" that's exactly what Centos was, and all versions up to and including 7 were RHEL rebuilds (Stream 8 became something different, but that doesn't matter for this question).

So, is Centos 7 affected by this change too?  As a Red hat project, I assume they aren't, and nothing has changed re: Centos and Centos 7 lifecycle on the centos.org website.  So my assumption is that Centos 7 will continue as is until it's end of life next year.

But there's a lot of assumptions in that statement.  Does anyone know anything that contradicts the above, or can link to an official announcement re: Centos 7 lifecycle changes?